# Can Mathematica solve nonlinear, coupled differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, differential-geometry

I've got two equations that describe a Geodesic on a sphere.
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2 u}{\mathrm d\lambda^2} - \cos u \sin u \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm d\lambda} \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm d\lambda} = 0 \\
\frac{\mathrm d^2 v}{\mathrm d\lambda^2} - 2\cot u \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm d\lambda} \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm d\lambda} = 0
$$

Can Mathematica solve these equations? I'm still pretty new, but this is my attempt so far:

```
Eq1 = Derivative[2][u] - Cos[u]*Sin[u]*D[v, λ]*D[v, λ] == 0
Eq2 = Derivative[2][v] + 2*Cot[u]*D[u, λ]*D[v, λ] == 0
NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {u, v}, λ]
```

But I'm not capturing the second derivative properly:

`NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function u^′′ appears with no arguments.`

Comment: u and v need to be specified as `u[lambda]` and `v[lambda]`

Comment: @Quarkly: What is represented by $(u,v)?$ Lat/long of a great circle? I plotted it 3D but there is a waviness.

Comment: @Narasimham - Yes, latitude and longitude of a 2D surface embedded in a 3D sphere.

Comment: @Quarkly Trying to verify the geodesic great circle for you. If not appropriate please feel free so we can roll back..

Comment: @ Quarky: Remember having seen such  in DG text reference by DJ Struik,  but have no copy with me now. Also when the sign before Cot[u] in second equation is changed, situation remains the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were syntactic and conceptual problems with your formulation.

Conceptually, `NDSolve` is a *numerical* solver, so you need to specify boundary conditions as well as a numerical range of integration for the independent variable, which were missing in your formulation.

Syntactically, `NDSolve` was complaining about the fact that you had not specified the independent variable for the $u$ and $v$ functions each time. A human reader might be able to infer that from context, but a computer system has to have it all spelled out unequivocally.

Here is an example to show you how you might be able to set this up. Note that I have made no attempt to choose reasonable constraints and boundary conditions; I have just chosen numbers that would give a solution, to give you a jump start on the syntax.

```
Eq1 = Derivative[2][u][λ] - Cos[u[λ]] Sin[u[λ]] D[v[λ], λ] D[v[λ], λ] == 0
Eq2 = Derivative[2][v][λ] + 2 Cot[u[λ]] D[u[λ], λ] D[v[λ], λ] == 0
NDSolve[
  {Eq1, Eq2, 
   u[0] == 1000, u'[0] == 5, v'[0] == 5, v[0] == 1000}, 
  {u, v}, {λ, 1, 2}
]
```

[image]

Comment: If you think about what Mathematica is doing here, it's mind boggling.

Answer (score 1):

Seems wavy, not like a great circle?

```
{r[t_], th[t_]} = {u[t], v[t]} /. First[%]
Plot[{r[λ], th[λ]}, {λ, 0, 2 }]
ParametricPlot3D[
  {r[t] Cos[th[t]], r[t] Sin[th[t]], r[t]}, 
  {t, 0, Pi/2}
]
```

[image]

Also plotted both possibilities for (lat,long); the great circle is not seen.

```
Eq1 = Derivative[2][u][λ] - 
    Cos[u[λ]] Sin[u[λ]] D[v[λ], λ] D[v[λ], λ] == 0;
Eq2 = Derivative[2][v][λ] + 
    2 Cot[u[λ]] D[u[λ], λ] D[v[λ], λ] == 0;
NDSolve[
  {Eq1, Eq2, u[0] == 10, 
   u'[0] == 5, v'[0] == 5, 
   v[0] == 10},
  {u, v}, {λ, 0, 2}];

{ph[t_], th[t_]} = {u[t], v[t]} /. First[%]
Plot[{r[λ], th[λ]}, {λ, 0, 2}]
g1 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ph[t]] Cos[th[t]], Cos[ph[t]] Sin[th[t]], 
   Sin[ph[t]]}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
g2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[th[t]] Cos[ph[t]], Cos[th[t]] Sin[ph[t]], 
   Sin[th[t]]}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
sph = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ph] Cos[th], Cos[ph] Sin[th], 
   Sin[ph]}, {ph, -1.5, 1.5}, {th, 0, Pi 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.05]]
Show[{g1, g2, sph}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]